# What are the differences between a @nrwl/js library and a @nrwl/workspace library?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have created both in a testing environment but am still having trouble to differentiate between the use cases of the two. They both have the same file structure, slightly different `tsconfig.json` file, `@nrwl/js` library is stricter by 2 extra props. Otherwise they seem to be the same. On the official site there is no info regarding the differences between the two.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: wondering the same thing myself

Comment: Same. Would really appreciate it if someone from nrwl could comment!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### @nrwl/js:library

Use to generate a **generic** typescript library.

```bash
npx nx g @nrwl/js:library --name myLibrary --directory common --buildable # creates libs/common/my-library
```

### @nrwl/workspace:library

Use to generate a **UI focused** typescript library.

```bash
npx nx g @nrwl/workspace:library --name myLibrary --directory common --buildable # creates libs/common/my-library
```

## Differences

1. `@nrwl/workspace:library` has a `.babelrc` file that is not present in `@nrwl/js:library`
2. `@nrwl/workspace:library` has a `jest.config.ts` that supports `.tsx` files while `@nrwl/js:library` only supports `.ts` files
3. The `tsconfig` files are different

## How I found the differences

I created a library using each generator

```bash
npx nx g @nrwl/js:library --name library --directory common/nrwljs --buildable
npx nx g @nrwl/workspace:library --name library --directory common/nrwlworkspace --buildable
```

Then I compared the files of each

```bash
diff -rq libs/common/nrwljs/library libs/common/nrwlworkspace/
Only in libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library: .babelrc
Files libs/common/nrwljs/library/README.md and libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library/README.md differ
Files libs/common/nrwljs/library/jest.config.ts and libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library/jest.config.ts differ
Files libs/common/nrwljs/library/package.json and libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library/package.json differ
Files libs/common/nrwljs/library/project.json and libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library/project.json differ
Files libs/common/nrwljs/library/src/index.ts and libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library/src/index.ts differ
Only in libs/common/nrwljs/library/src/lib: common-nrwljs-library.spec.ts
Only in libs/common/nrwljs/library/src/lib: common-nrwljs-library.ts
Only in libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library/src/lib: common-nrwlworkspace-library.spec.ts
Only in libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library/src/lib: common-nrwlworkspace-library.ts
Files libs/common/nrwljs/library/tsconfig.json and libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library/tsconfig.json differ
Files libs/common/nrwljs/library/tsconfig.lib.json and libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library/tsconfig.lib.json differ
Files libs/common/nrwljs/library/tsconfig.spec.json and libs/common/nrwlworkspace/library/tsconfig.spec.json differ
```

Comment: Also according to docs, @nrwl/workspace:library is now deprecated and would be removed in Nx v16.

Comment:  for "How I found the differences". The best way to learn about NX is comparing generated code (besides digging into the code)

Answer (score -2):

It's about the options you can use for each generator. Here are the documentation of the generators:

- https://nx.dev/packages/workspace/generators/library
- https://nx.dev/packages/angular/generators/library

Angular generator has some specific options, eg to include routing or lazy behaviours.